# RethinkDB: multiple comparisons filtering

Tags: python, python-2.6, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

By the docs, it seems that in order to filter all users that are 30 years old OR 40 years old, I can do this (with python):

```
r.table("users").filter((r.row["age"].eq(30)) | (r.row["age"].eq(40))).run(conn)
```

Say I have a list based on input / request: [12, 14, 18, 88, 33 ...], how do I filter all the users that are in the age of one of the elements in the list above by iterating it (and not doing it hard coded)?

Comment: It would be great, if you include necessary imports into your code to be sure, what package we are exactly using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's one way to do it

```
valid_ages = [12, 14, 18, 88, 33]

r.table("users").filter(lambda user:
    r.expr(valid_ages).contains(user["age"])
).run(connection)
```

If you were using an index and `get_all`, you could do

```
r.table("users").get_all(*valid_ages, index="age").run(connection)
```

(You need to create the index age before that)